# SQL concat within a dynamic select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

In my query why concat not working. I need (%) sign after int value in Factory Total row only.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @cols = 
    STUFF(
                (SELECT distinct ',' + quotename([date]) 
                FROM Table_1 
                WHERE Date between '20230101' and '20230828'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
set @query = 'select LineName, ' + @cols + 
                ' from (select LineName,[date],ISNULL(Sum(PlanProduction),0) other_columns 
                    from Table_17Q group by LineName, [date] 
                    UNION ALL SELECT ''zFactory Total'',date, Concat(Sum(PlanProduction),''%'') other_columns from 
                    Table_1 group by LineName, [date]
                    ) 
                        x pivot (max(other_columns) for [date] in (' + @cols 
                + ')) p Order by LineName'  ;
 execute( @query)
```

If i use int value replaceing % sign than it work fine but char not working. strange!

Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '820%' to data type int.

Comment: As you are using `Sum()` function on `PlanProduction` column; that means; It's an integer.

You are trying to concat this integer with a string i.e. `%`.


You can try `CAST`ing your integer column to string while concatenating

Comment: I strongly suggest you get into the *good* habit of formatting your code; that SQL is so difficult to read.

Comment: It's also generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: with out table1 nobody can debug it

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Why are you trying to concat a `%` on anyway? Side note: `SELECT distinct ',' + quotename([date])` is going to be slow, might be better to do `GROUP BY date` then just `SELECT ',' + quotename([date])`.

Comment: Side note: Did you indent to group by both `LineName` and `[date]` in the second part of your query or did you intend just `group by [date]`?.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```
select LineName,[date],
       ISNULL(Sum(PlanProduction),0) other_columns       -- <<<
from Table_17Q group by LineName, [date] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ''zFactory Total'',date,
        Concat(Sum(PlanProduction),''%'') other_columns  -- <<<
```

`UNION ALL` requires corresponding column to have the same data type and the data type of `ISNULL(Sum(PlanProduction),0)` is numeric.

In order to avoid implicit conversion the other_columns from first query should be explicitly casted to varchar:

```
select LineName,[date],
     ISNULL(Sum(PlanProduction),0) other_columns 

=>

select LineName,[date],
     CAST(ISNULL(Sum(PlanProduction),0) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) other_columns
```

---

Also:

```
SET @cols = 
    STUFF(
                (SELECT distinct ',' + quotename([date]) 
                FROM Table_1 
                WHERE Date between '20230101' and '20230828'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
```

is [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
 SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(sub.[date]), ',') 
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [date]
       FROM Table_1 
       WHERE Date between '20230101' and '20230828') AS sub;
```

Comment: I got the solution after adding cast as varchar in all statement.  CAST(ISNULL(Sum(PlanProduction),0) AS VARCHAR). Thanks everybody for try this. Thanks specially Lukasz Szozda https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070879/lukasz-szozda.

Comment: Also Thanks Tusar https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473648/tushar